# Why is the word "3-way" used when TCP connection involves only 2 parties?

Tags: tcp

Sorry if the question seems weird, but I'm not a native English speaker and my understanding of a adjective "n-way" means their are n directions or n parties involved in the object being described. As far as I know, establishing a TCP connection involves only 2 parties talking back and forth in a 3-stage manner. Was my understanding wrong, that a third party could be the sender or receiver of some messages, or "3-way handshake" was just a short phrase that's not carefully chosen?

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: You're right that "3-part" or "3-stage" is more descriptive... but it's called "3-way"... I'll be interested to see if you get a good answer -- I think it's probably just an artifact of history at this point.